# Display pdf file from the group folder when UIButton is pressed

Tags: iphone, pdf, ios6, uicollectionview

I am trying to use Leaves sample code from GitHub to display pdf file when UIButton is pressed but when executing the project it is giving error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: [LeavesCache setDataSource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Added Exception breakpoint and found that problem is at this line

From LeavesView.m

```
pageCache = [[LeavesCache alloc] initWithPageSize:self.bounds.size];

 - (void) initialize {
backgroundRendering = NO;
pageCache = [[LeavesCache alloc] initWithPageSize:self.bounds.size];
   }
```

From LeavesCache.m

```
- (id) initWithPageSize:(CGSize)aPageSize
{
if (self = [super init]) {
pageSize = aPageSize;
pageCache = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
return self;
}
```

From LeavesView.m

```
- (void) setDataSource:(id<LeavesViewDataSource>)value {
pageCache.dataSource = value;
  }
```

Difference is that Leaves project is using Tableviewcontroller but i m using collection view controller with the storyboard segue. In detailviewcontroller have a uibutton which displays pdf file when it is pressed. But when pressing that uibutton it is giving error.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a dataSource for your collection view controller, then you don't need to call it at all.  All a dataSource does is tell your class where to look for the data.  Your error is that there is no dataSource property in LeavesCache, and you're trying to set one.

Comment: there is property in leaves cache @property (assign) id<LeavesViewDataSource> dataSource;

Comment: For some reason, it is not recognizing it. It's telling you it's not recognizing the setDataSource as a valid signature to a message.

Comment: In the debugging it is showing that datasource = (objc_object*) 0x00000000

Comment: What are you passing in as 'value?' Your error message is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: [LeavesCache setDataSource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance, so something about that message is bad.  Maybe 'value' does not contain a valid object?  Other than that there isn't enough code to see the cause.

Comment: I just found in debugging crash log it says that nsobject doesnot recognize selector and nsobject is LeavesCache and selector is the uibutton which i m pressing to display pdf file

Comment: This is the coding in the detailviewcontroller for uibutton to display pdf file- (IBAction)ReadAction:(id)sender {
    
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];}
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        
        // Get destination view
        PDFViewController *pdfviewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
        [pdfviewController setSelectedButton:tagIndex];
    }
}

Comment: The message you're describing (doesn't recognize selector) means that an object is getting a method call that doesn't exist in the object.  It looks from your description that that object is a LeavesCache, but I'm now now sure what selector you're crashing on.

Comment: i m really confused if you can please specify exactly how i can fix this to make it work.

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted the entire crash log.

Comment: delegate = (objc_object *) 0x00000000
pageCache = (LeavesCache *) 0x07ad5d10
NSObject (NSObject)
isa= (Class)LeavesCache 
[0] = (Class) <error:unknown Class>
pageCache = (NSMutableDictionary *) 0x07aeaab0 0key/value pairs
dataSource = (objc_object *) 0x00000000

 [DetailViewController PDFAction:]

pdf= (CGPDFDocumentRef)0x00000000

Comment: It's still hard to tell from what little we have here. A lot of your items are null. Are you calling things in an object which is already null?